# PII and the Content Moderator API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

In the overview documentation for Content Moderator - there is mention of identifying PII using the API, but I cant find any detail about this.  Is there some documentation describing what PII can be identified?

Thanks

Comment: I could only find this: `Detecting faces is important in the context of content moderation because you may not want your users to upload
any personally identifiable information (PII) and risk their privacy and your brand.`

Answer (score 0):

James,

Thanks for the feedback. We will add the information below to the Text API Overview page that you probably saw.

The PII feature mentioned on the [Text API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/content-moderator/text-moderation-api) page outputs this information if detected within the text input:

1. Email
2. Phone
3. Mailing Address

Try it live on the [API Reference](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/57cf753a3f9b070c105bd2c1/operations/57cf753a3f9b070868a1f66f) page by using the "Open API Testing Console" buttons and selecting your region (of your API key).

**SAMPLE TEST RESULTS**

For the input text: “My email is someone@address.com phone at 999-999-9999 staying at 99999 99th Avenue City WA, 99999.”
And given my API Key: (See where to get it from)

**You will get a response like this one:**

**(Note: Replace the dummy PII in the input text with realistic content to see the results.).**

```
{
    "OriginalText": "My email is someone@address.com phone at 999-999-9999 staying at 99999 99th Avenue City WA, 99999",
    "NormalizedText": "My email is someone@address.com phone at 999-999-9999 staying at 99999 99th Avenue City WA, 99999",
    "Misrepresentation": null,
    "PII": {
    "Email": [
     {
        "Detected": "someone@address.com",
        "SubType": "Regular",
        "Text": "someone@address.com",
        "Index": 12
     }
    ],
    "IPA": [],
     "Phone": [
     {
        "CountryCode": "US",
        "Text": "999-999-9999",
        "Index": 50
     }
     ],
     "Address": [
     {
        "Text": "99th Avenue City WA, 99999",
        "Index": 80
     }
     ]
  },
  "Language": "eng",
  "Terms": null,
  "Status": {
  "Code": 3000,
  "Description": "OK",
  "Exception": null
 },
"TrackingId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Let me know if this helps.